# How to add one-click unsubscribe functionality to email newletters?

Tags: email, usability

I'd like to customize the "unsubscribe" links in our email newsletters so that they remove the recipient with a single click.  Right now they just point to a generic page where the user has to enter their email address and select the newsletter from which they'd like to unsubscribe.

It seems like this should be pretty straightforward, i.e. just include the email address and newsletter id as url parameters.  But when I looked at examples from the lists I subscribe to, many don't include a recognizable address and most appear to be using what looks like guids and/or hashed values in the parameters.  From that, I'm guessing that I should be hashing or otherwise encoding some information to prevent malicious abuse of the unsubscribe form.

So my question is really about best practices and not reinventing the wheel.  Is there a standard way to handle this sort of functionality?  More specifically, are there reasons not to include the recipient's email address as part of the url?  This seems just simple enough that it feels like I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Since there really isn't a real answer, I'll just comment:  It can't really be a hash unless you have a lookup table for the hash to the user id.  What I do is encrypt the user id, so that when I get it back, I can decrypt it and unsubscribe the user.

Comment: having email in URL might work unless you don't want people to unsubscribe other peoples email addresses, encrypting email will work, JWT will also work as you can't modify contents.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can encode a URL like so:

```
http://yourserver.com/unsubscribe/<encoded-email>/<expiration>/<signature>
```

Where `<signature>` is something like `HMAC(secretkey, "<encoded-email>/<expiration>")`. Encoded-email can just be a URL-encoding of the email, or it can be an actually encrypted (AES+CBC+Base64 or similar) version of the email. Using full encryption would seem to be of little use though - since the person receiving this has their own email address anyway.

This signature scheme has the advantage of not needing any database storage, while remaining secure against malicious attempts to unsubscribe someone.

Alternately (or in addition to the above), you can send a confirmation mail out to confirm the user's intent. This avoids problems if the user forwards the email.

Comment: So if I understand, you're basically saying to include emailaddress, and a hash of emailaddress+secretkey in the unsubscribe link; then my unsubscribe web page will rehash emailaddress+secretkey and make sure it matches the hashed value passed to the page.  And this prevents abuse because the secretkey value exists only on our server.  That makes sense so far, but what's the purpose of <expiration>?

Comment: @Matt, expiration is to ensure these urls don't need to remain secret forever and a day. :)

Comment: @bdonlan, I'm not sure what you mean by "secret urls"; are you just saying that the signature should effectively expire so that I can periodically change the secret key?  Or is this something to do with REST and the structure of your sample URL.  We're old-school, so my actual url will look more like http://myserver.com/unsub.aspx?addr=encoded-email&sig=signature-val, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I mean, it expires so if it's posted publicly, the window of time in which it can be used to unsubscribe that person is limited. This is mitigated if you use a confirmation mail, of course.

Comment: Got it.  I spent some quality time with google and MSDN, and an HMAC looks like just what I wanted but didn't know how to ask for.  Thanks again.

Comment: @bdonlan <expiration> - is it encoded DateTime value (like email address)?

Comment: @Armstrongest Any examples for java ?

Comment: @SanKrish Well, the language parts can be easily converted from C# to Java, but the HMAC libraries would likely be very different in Java.

Comment: @Armstrongest Thanks for the reply . Can you please elaborate on using expiration . how can i achieve it ?

Comment: @Armstrongest how to create expiration token . Any references would be highly usefull

Answer (score 4):

If your mailing list software uses old-school best practices, there should be an 'unsubscribe' email address - emailing to that address from the address you want to unsubscribe (possibly with a fixed subject line) generally does the trick (along with sending a confirmation email). In that case, adding a properly formatted 'mailto' link should do the trick.

Comment: I like this approach, but I'm dealing with an existing code-base and architecture that makes it easier to go the web-based route.

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons for not having a plain text email address in the query the  in the URL are that you don't want malicious users unsubscribing your customers from your mailing list.

The second which probably would only affect companies sending millions of e-mails, is to make it harder for spammers to 'sniff' for genuine email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

It's not safe to embed email addresses in a newsletter. Not sure about yours but many newsletters ended up in some archive on the web. There are spam bots specifically designed to harvest addresses from mailing list archives.

Email is a safer technology for this. Setup a mail account for unsubscribe and get Email address from mail headers. If you use any mailing list software, it should handle this already.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a somehow simple method in a web application but I'm not sure if it is   efficient and secure enough for other web app's purposes .

In my app when the user click on the unsubscribe link, I forward them to a page on my server with a Query string which is a combination of user email address and it's unique id in my `DB` (both encrypted preferably).

Then in the page load function of my page, first I `decrypt` the `Email address`, and then I check to see if the email address exist in my DB and then if the answer is TRUE, I check if the `ID` and the `Email address` are related and finally I remove the user according to other criterion.

I think it would do the job without any extra data entry to the `DB`.

Now I'm looking for a way to find out if the person who has clicked the link is the first hand person who I have send the email to or the email has been forwarded to him/her. So that no one other than the real user can (at least easily) unsubscribe him/her!

*[Asking for a security question before  finalizing the unsubscribing process is one thing that I have thought about so far]*

Answer (score 0):

I assign a unique 32-character identifier string (with MySQL: `MD5(UUID())`) to each e-mail address and only submit that identifier in the unsubscribe link.

Answer (score -7):

I give each email I send an ID, then look up the email ID when they click unsubscribe.

http://www.foo.com/unsubscribe.asp?ID=1234

And then unsubscribe the email address I sent 1234 to.

Comment: Anyone reading this, do NOT follow this advice. Not only does his advice not scale well in any mailing system, but it is not secure. He has a easy to discern pattern with no verification for the authenticity of the user who holds the email. If you don't want overhead and a easy but secure-enough to implement system look at the accepted answer.

Comment: Someone could make a script with curl and unsubscribe all your users. Be carefull with that approach. Use a unique token for each user, or make them fill their email with some other verification.