# How should a RFC 8058 List-Unsubscribe or List-Unsubscribe-Post be responded to by a web server?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, email, w3c

This is about the new unsubscribe feature implemented in the email header that supports 'One-Click' unsubscribe. This feature is supported by many email clients like email reading apps on smartphones. Other questions like [How to add one-click unsubscribe functionality to email newletters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240915/how-to-add-one-click-unsubscribe-functionality-to-email-newletters) have been asked and answered over ten years ago and have nothing to do with the new feature.

The List-Unsubscribe feature supports two methods (maybe a third for POST, I'm not sure), one method is for sending an email, like a `mailto`, with the details needed to accomplish an unsubscribe, the other method is via a URL. My question is about the List-Unsubscribe via URL. I have no problem getting the email reader to display (above the email) the unsubscribe button/link with either the email (`mailto`) or URL (or both) in the email meta header. (I create the email with Python, but this is NOT a Python question). For reference please see RFC 8058 and RFC 2369. What is not clear to me is:
How should the web server respond to the unsubscribe request? I am expecting that the user should not have to take any action beyond clicking on the email client unsubscribe button. Should the webserver just respond with a blank page to the email client, or should it respond with some code? Is there an option for the email client to display a success page. (Is it an option to have the email client display a page? {I don't need this feature but someone might})

[RFC2369](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2369.txt)
[RFC 8058][3]

[3]: [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8058![iPhone](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8058!%5BiPhone) email 'Mail' app feature to unsubscribe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXteb.jpg)

Comment: Please do not repost questions.

Comment: I can’t find anything on that in either of those RFCs. There’s talk about how the user should be able to review what exact message gets send, before it gets send - but on how they should be notified, whether the action was successful or ran into some error, there appears to be zilch, as far as I can see. If the mail client would open the URL in a browser / webview, then any clear-text response for the user to read would do, I suppose - but if this gets implemented as some form of background request by a mail client, then I guess we need some additional specification on that.

Comment: RFC 8058, Section 3.2: "The target of the POST action is the same as the one in the GET action for a manual unsubscription, so this is intended to allow the same server code to handle both." This seems to imply that any 200 response will do. It stands to reason that mail clients will check the status code, and given the statement above they can make no assumptions whatsoever about the response body, so I expect them to ignore it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I reposted the question because the comments seemed to not understand that the unsubscribe link I was referring to was not in the email body and they seemed to not understand the new email header feature. Hopefully I made it clear this time. As a side note there really should be a way to converse about closed questions.

Comment: The way you converse about closed questions is to post about the question on Meta where you can plead your case to get a question reopened when you think that others do not understand what you're asking. You edit that question to make it clearer and to add relevant details.

Comment: @JayBlanchard
" to post about the question on Meta" What does that mean?

Comment: See [What should you do if nobody answers your question? Can you repost it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265233)

Comment: The [edit] link is to be preferred though. In particular for likely duplicates. Less wall of text, showing more research, and even better: tests of your own. Bounties are also more useful than topic dilution, moving targets or soliciting attention through reposts.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ @MatthewCox